# Setting the height of the bottom tab bar issues! Only works with hard values, not parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to set the height in the bottom tab bar (using react navigation). I have global variables set in a gloabls.js file which work perfectly and get set in my App.js file fine. e.g.

```
    global.App_paddingLeft = 3,
    global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = '8%',
```

In my App.js i do this:

```
//Tabs across the bottom of the screen
const MainScreenTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    
    OtherStack,

  },
  {

    tabBarOptions: {

      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black', //white 
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff8278',
        height: global.App_BottomTabBarHeight   //'8%'
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
      },
      showLabel: false
    },
    
  }
  
);
```

The height wont set with the variable `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = '8%'`. This `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight` definitely passes the '8%' through to the App.js file as i've console.logged it.

I've also tried doing this:
`height: Dimensions.get('window').height * global.App_BottomTabBarHeight`, where `global.App_BottomTabBarHeight = 0.08`, but still nothing

Why can't i set the height to '8%' ?

If i manually type `height: '8%'` it works fine. Strange

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's safer to stay away from `global object` if you wanna have some "Global styling || theme" ...

I'd suggest you create a `theme > style.js` file and stores all these styles in it like

```
 export const App_paddingLeft = 3;
```

Then you could reference these in your bottom-tabs style, and It'll work just fine...